# Array of all possible combinations in the order of index from another array of strings - TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to get an array of strings from another array of strings with following conditions :-

1: Should contain concatenation of first letter of the word at the first index of array with all other elements EX - ["AH", "BEE", "JAMES"] --> ["ABEEJAMES"]

2: Should contain concatenation of first letter of the word at the first and second index of array with all other elements EX - ["AH", "BEE", "JAMES"] --> ["ABJAMES"]
This needs to be done till the last index of the array

#### Input array of strings

```
const updateFullNameParts = ["AH", "BEE", "JAMES"];
```

#### Current implementation

```
const noSpaceName = updateFullNameParts.join("");
   const createCombination = fullNameParts.map((name) => {
       const fullNamePartsCopy = fullNameParts;
         const innerResult = fullNamePartsCopy.map((nameCopy) => {
            let innerCopy = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < fullNamePartsCopy.length; i++) {
              if (name === fullNamePartsCopy[i]) {
                innerCopy = innerCopy + fullNamePartsCopy[i];
              } else if (nameCopy === fullNamePartsCopy[i])
                innerCopy = innerCopy + fullNamePartsCopy[i];
              else innerCopy = innerCopy + fullNamePartsCopy[i].slice(0, 1);
            }
            return innerCopy;
          });
```

#### Expected array of strings

```
["ABEEJAMES", "ABJAMES", "ABJ", "AHBJAMES", "ABEEJ", "AHBEEJAMES", "AHBEE"]
```

#### Array should not contain

```
["BJAMES", "AB", "BAJAMES", "A"]
```

Basically the array should only contain combinations in the order of index.

Is there a low time complexity solution for this?

Comment: "AHBJ" also should be there right?

Comment: Yes it should be be there

Answer (score 0):

First make list from each word. (first letter and whole word).
Then create list of possible words using couple of `forEach` loops.

```js
const updateFullNameParts = ["AH", "BEE", "JAMES"];

const list = (arr) => {
  let output = [""];
  arr.forEach((word) => {
    const items = [word[0], word];
    const temp = [];
    output.forEach((xx) => items.forEach((yy) => temp.push(`${xx}${yy}`)));
    output = [...temp];
  });
  
  // Add special cases.
  // First word and second word
  output.push(arr.slice(0, 2).join(''));
  
  return output;
};

console.log(list(updateFullNameParts));
```

Another variant and simplified with `reduce`

```js
const arr = ["AH", "BEE", "JAMES"];

const list = arr.reduce(
  (acc, word) => [word[0], word].flatMap((yy) => acc.map((xx) => `${xx}${yy}`)),
  [""]
);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Is it possible to have AHBEE also in the list??

Comment: @HarshNagalla, Yes. This will be special case, you can add at the end of list generation. I have updated the answer in the first approach adding the special case.